# Spring doesn't load JavaTimeModule after Spring Update just load legacy one

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I updated my project from spring boot 2.3.8 to 2.6.7 and I upgrade the jackson version to 2.13.2

I set the JavaTimeModule like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
  public ObjectMapper objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
    builder.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    builder.modulesToInstall(new JavaTimeModule());
    return builder.build();
  }
```

I have a Test checking if i set the JaveTimeModule correctly:

```
 def "jackson config - adding JavaTimeModule and disable ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE"(){

        when:
        def objectMapper = jacksonConfig.objectMapperBuilder()

        then:
        !objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().isEnabled(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
        !objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        objectMapper.getRegisteredModuleIds().contains("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module")
        objectMapper.getRegisteredModuleIds().contains("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule")
    }
```

The test fails.
Everytime I debug it, I just see that
"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module" and "jackson-datatype-jsr310" as registered Modules.
I don't see "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule" as a registered module